# how to run robotium testcase using maven?

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven, robotium

i have 2 library projects,1 main project which is using both the library projects, and a test project. I am using maven to build my app.it is working fine.I have added the modules like

```
 <modules>
    <module>lib1</module>
    <module>lib2</module>
    <module>main app</module>
    <module>AutomatedUnitTestFrameWork</module>

</modules>
```

i am using robotium for testing my app.When i run mvn install command it is showing the status as success.But testcases are not running and i am not getting any test result.Do i need to add junit depedency also or surefire plugin?please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add surefire plugin to detect the test cases in your java file. So you need to add its dependency.